# Project Euler #2 in R

Tags: r

I'm a novice at programming and I've been trying Project Euler to learn more about R.

The question that's stumping me is as follows:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed 4 million, find the sum of the even valued terms.

I've started to tackle this problem by setting the first couple numbers in the sequence:

```
num <- c(1, 2)
```

Next I'm trying to create a function `fib()` that will sum the last two numbers in `num` and append them to the vector.

My first attempt has been to do the following:

```
num <- c(1, 2)

fib <- function(x) {
    sum <- sum(tail(x,2))
        while (sum <= 4e6) {
        x <- append(x, sum)
        return(x)
    }
}
```

But when I run this I only get one additional Fibonacci number:

```
> fib(num)
[1] 1 2 3
```

In turn, I tried moving `return(x)`:

```
num <- c(1, 2)

fib <- function(x) {
    sum <- sum(tail(x,2))
        while (sum <= 4e6) {
        x <- append(x, sum)
    }
    return(x)
}
```

But this seems to only create an infinite loop.

As a caveat, I'm comfortable summing the even-valued terms with a modulo and I'll do this after I work out this particular issue.

Can you point out where I'm going wrong with my code? (If you could give me a bump in the right direction without providing an explicit solution that would be even more appreciated.)

Thanks to @Minnow and @blakeoft for helping me to get a handle on this. Here's what I ended up doing to solve this problem:

**SPOILER ALERT**

```
num <- c(1, 2)

fib <- function(x) {
    last2 <- sum(tail(x,2))
            while (last2 <= 4000000) {
                x <- append(x, last2)
                last2 <- sum(tail(x,2))
            }
    return(x)
}
```

I won't include the last bit with the modulo since I want to keep the answer specific to the initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without giving it away:

Walk through your loop and see if you can figure out the expected output.  You're close, but the sequence of events is not going to yield what you expect.

Comment: An additional hint: At the end of each iteration of the loop, pay attention to what happened to each of the variables. There are only 3 declared, namely `num`, `sum` and `x`.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a language-specific problem? You don't really need a function, just three variables say `prev`, `curr` and `next`. Preload the first two and prime the even values' sum. You know how to set the value of `next`, then process it and shove the values back through your history.

You didn't want a specific answer, but now you have accepted one, this is what I meant - it's not `r` but it shows how simple it can be.

```
int sum = 2;
int prev = 1;
int curr = 2;
int next = 0;
while (next < 4000000) {
    next = prev + curr;
    if (next % 2 == 0)
        sum += next;
    prev = curr;
    curr = next;
}
printf ("%d", sum);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with this, but I'm not clear on how to shove them back through history without a loop.

Comment: I expanded my answer now your actual question was satisfied.

Comment: Cool, I've never seen this approach before so thank you for sharing it. I'm going to up vote this answer in a few more hours once I have votes again.